# Using an if else statement in R?

Tags: r

Write a function called *dayplan(temperature,work)*. The Function should at first check if it is dealing with realistic values. Thereby *temperature∈[-20,40]* and *work∈{´Yes´, ´No´}*. For realistic values the function should give out these values:

When *temperature>=20* and *job==´Yes´*, then "Eat ice cream"

When *temperature>=20* and *job==´No´*, then "Sea"

When *temperature >20* and *job ==´Yes´*, then "Shopping"

When *temperature<20* and *job==´No´*, then "Bed"

Answer (score 0):

The outline of the function can look something like this:

```
dayplan <- function(temperature, work){
  if(...){
    if(...){
      print("Eat ice cream.")
    } else if(...) {
       ...
       ...
    }
  } else {
    print("Inputs not feasible.")
  }
}
```

Fill in the gaps using the conditions for each activity.

Comment: Hey, so I don't really know how to incorporate the "Shopping" and "Bed" options into this. Also, do I need to set the limit for temperature under 40?                                                                                                  
  dayplan <- function(temperature, work){
  if(temperature>=20){
    if(work='Yes'){
      print("Eat ice cream.")
    } else if(work='No') {
       print("Sea")
       ...
    }
  } else {
    print("Inputs not feasible.")
  }
}

Comment: According to what you wrote, temperature should be less than or equal to 40 but greater than or equal to -20. For your first question, it's the same thing as the ice cream option: use the print() function.

Comment: Hey, sorry but this is what I have in the end and it isn't really working. dayplan <- function (temperature, work) { if(temperature>=20) { if(work=='Yes') { print("Eat ice cram") } else if (work == 'Non') { print("Sea") } else if(temperature < 20) { if(work == 'Yes') { print("Shopping") } } else if (work == 'No'){ print("Bed") } } else { print("Input not feasible") }

Comment: That's not how it works. I suggest you read up on how ifelse statements work in R.